# Bash Script To Listen For Shell Command Output

Tags: macos, bash, shell

Quick question. How would I go about having a shell script to do the following:

- execute unix command (pmset -g ps) to check the output of that script every 5 seconds, and then if the output of that command falls to below say 40% (example of output is: 'Currenty drawing from 'AC Power'
  -iBox  100%; charging'), then for it to run a unix shell script...

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit, for Bash 2.05 *and later*:**

```
#!/bin/bash
tab=$'\t'
while true  # run forever, change to stop on some condition
do
    threshold=100
    until (( threshold < 40 ))
    do
        sleep 5
        result=$(pmset -g ps)
        threshold="${result#*iBox$tab}"
        threshold="${threshold%\%*}"
    done
    shell_script
done
```

**Original, for Bash 3.2 and later:**

```
#!/bin/bash
pattern='[0-9]+'    # works if there's only one sequence of digits in the output, a more selective pattern is possible if needed
while true  # run forever, change to stop on some condition
do
    threshold=100
    until (( threshold < 40 ))
    do
        sleep 5
        result=$(pmset -g ps)
        [[ $result =~ $pattern ]]
        threshold=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    done
    shell_script
done
```

Comment: ./listener.sh: line 10: conditional binary operator expected
./listener.sh: line 10: syntax error near `=~'
./listener.sh: line 10: `        [[ $result =~ $pattern ]]' any ideas??

Comment: @Elliot: What version of Bash? Are you using the value of `$pattern` as shown in the second line or something different?

Comment: @Dennis: Am using exactly the same thing as shown above, however have an `echo "execute script"` instead of actually executing a script if the conditions are true for testing purposes ... am using bash version 2.05b.0(1)

Comment: @Elliot: Unfortunately, regex matching was added in Bash 3.1 (but should be used only in 3.2 and later). I also noticed a bug in my script. I'll fix that and post a version that will work with Bash 2.05b.

Comment: @Dennis: Thanks very much - it's appreciated :)

Comment: @Dennis: thanks for the update, am currently getting the following error each 5 seconds - `./listener.sh: line 5: ((: Currenty drawing from 'AC Power'
 -iBox 100: syntax error in expression (error token is "drawing from 'AC Power'`
 -iBox 100")
^X./listener.sh: line 5: ((: Currenty drawing from 'AC Power'

Comment: @Elliot: What exactly is on line 5?

Comment: @Dennis: `until (( threshold < 40 ))`

Comment: @Elliot: Evidently I misunderstood the contents of the output of `pmset`. The brace expansions that split the number out of the text depend on it being a particular way. Evidently there's a tab between "-iBox" and the number. See my edited answer. I added a line near the beginning and changed the line with the first assignment to `threshold`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work

```
pmset -g ps | perl -pe 'if(/%.*Ibox ([0-9]+)%; ch.*$/ and $1 < 40){system "nameofshellscript"}'
```