# interactive shell script command line php

Tags: php, zend-framework, shell, command-line, interactive

I am trying to implement a feature on my web application to provide the user the ability to interact with the command line on the server.

The problem is: is it possible to integrate the command line with the web application so any result will be produced can be shown to the user even if the processes is still working in the background and any input can be taken and processed so it will be like -a function.

I have tried all the exec() shell_exec() i have tried to redirect the result of the interactive command by 2> SomeFile.txt but the output will not be the result of the interactive command

Comment: There are a lot of existing php-shells. You can look how they are designed and even use their code in your project (if they're under free license (: )

Comment: i am not trying to shell script php, i am trying to shell script another language using php ??

Comment: If you are using linux, in your command line, you can make use of a command-line listener as suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5135321/bash-script-to-listen-for-shell-command-output

Comment: You could also implement a port listener, and send commands and strings to that port, then the port listener forwards the messages to your web app or be stored in a database, so your app can grab data from time to time by way of ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.With commands return the output. Use:

[shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) — Execute command via shell and return the complete output as a string

[passthru](http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php) — Execute an external program and display raw output

[system](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) — Execute an external program and display the output

2.With commands not return the output. Use:

system or passthru then check return_var argument and print the output

```
system('touch readme.txt', $retval);
if(!$retval){
    print 'Touched file with success';
}
```

Or

```
if(!touch('readme.txt', time())){
    print 'Whoops, something went wrong...';
}
```

Comment: This wont help because when i use the shell_exec or any of the other methods, the command line processes is still open and i cant retrieve any of the data.and i cant send any data while it is open